# How do I specify the desired filename when taking screen captures with PhantomJS?

Tags: phantomjs

So I’m wanting to specify the screen capture file name is the root domain; eg. Example.png. At the moment my script uses the webpage Title Tag which when doing this for hundreds of URLs can look messy. Does anyone know what chances I need to make?

The code I’m using can be found here
http://j4n.co/blog/batch-rendering-screenshots-with-phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the filename inside the [`page.render()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html) function:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://example.com/', function () {
  page.render('example.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! How would I do this if I am doing it for multiple URL's though? Cheers